# How to calculate integral involving Bessel function?

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

$$\int_0^{\infty}y^{1+\frac{m+c}{2}}K_{c-m}(2b\sqrt{y})dy,$$

How to calculate this integral? Note that, $K_{c-m}$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

Comment: May we assume $b$ is positive?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $t = 2b\sqrt{y}$, then $\frac{t}{2b^2} dt = dy$, so
$$ \int_0^\infty \left(\frac{t}{2b}\right)^{2+m+c} K_{c-m}(t) \frac{t}{2b^2} dt $$
$$ \frac{(2b)^{-3-m-c}}{b} \int_0^\infty t^{3+m+c} K_{c-m}(t) dt $$
Now applying the integral identity [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.43),
$$ \frac{(2b)^{-3-m-c}}{b} 2^{2+m+c}\Gamma(m+2)\Gamma(c+2) $$
$$ \frac{b^{-4-m-c}}{2} \Gamma(m+2)\Gamma(c+2) $$

Comment: The link you provided seems to be using the first kind, no?

Comment: @Kira The identity you are supposed to apply is equation 10.43.19 in section (iv). You may have to scroll down to find it, but it is definitely using modified Bessel functions of the second kind.